# Loss is negative- DQN with BCE Loss function

Tags: classification, dqn, loss, binary-crossentropy

I am writing a code with DQN, using BCE as a loss function for the classification of a sequential time series. But while training, the loss value goes in negative. Also, accuracy and binary accuracy are low as well almost 20 %. I have tried tuning the hyperparameters as well.

Comment: Using RL for classification is a very bad idea, because you make everything at least 100x more difficult and slower to learn. Just use supervised learning, as usual.